# Why is my increment 0 when append to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this problem my var i = 0 is incrementing whenever I click the specific button which triggers increment. I tested it on console and increment is working it's going up by one whenever the button is pressed.
But here is the problem when I append paragraph and "i" in it, to a div in HTML it's just showing a "0" and it's not changing values like 1, 2, 3 when the button is clicked.
I wanted that it counts how many tasks are completed.
I tried to google it but couldn't find an answer.

Just to say that I'm still a beginner at JS and JQuery. So don't go hard on me. :D

```
var i = 0

$(".taskdone").append(`<p>${i}</p>`)

function createElement(e) {

$(".ul").append(`<div>
<li class="list"> ${e} </li>
<button onclick=" changeText(), deleteItem(this) " class="task-done"></button>
<hr>
</div>`)

function deleteItem(event) {
event.parentElement.remove();

$(".container").animate({
    height: "-=95px"
}, 800);

i++;

};


};
```

Comment: Can you show the code that defines and adds the click handler?

Comment: actually `i` is never incremented, how did you increment it in the console ?

Comment: There's no logic in your pasted code that increments `i`, so of course it does not increment.

Comment: In the code snippet you posted, you are assigning the value of `0` to `i`. It isn't being incremented anywhere.  You need to post enough of your code to demonstrate the issue, but not post too much so that the problem is buried.

Comment: The template literal is evaluated immediately: it results in a string `"<p>0</p>"` without any dynamic link to the variable `i` that might increment later on. Maybe that is the confusion here?

Comment: Where you increment `i`, you should also do `$(".taskdone>p").text(i);`.

Comment: Okay this is it like I said there is a button that deletes item it means the task is done and on click "i" is incremented by 1 but in HTML on the website, it's showing 0, also to mention that there is another button that executes function createElement(), everything is working well just this increment on website number is always 0 but when I open console and type "i" it's showing number(times button got clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that `i` does `increment`, but an `increment` in `i` doesn't causes `$(".taskdone")` to get updated.

If you `console.log` the `i` after each button click you would see it updating.

You can just manually update the `p` inside `.taskdone` once an `incremention` took a place like this:

```
$(".taskdone p").text(i)
```

Comment: So there is no way to update that paragraph on clicking that button for the task done with increment solution, whatever I try it's always 0 but when I log it in the console it's working ok. Is there any other way to count when I click on that button and that number in website change.

Comment: @Alco try to read my answer again. all you need to do is to update the `p` text after `i++` took a place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time I must say I tried that before and a lot of other options as well and you gave me idea once an increment takes place a have to execute this :

    $(".taskdone p").text(i)

And I added this to a function deleteItem() where increment is happening its working now and numbers are updating so simple. I got pretty much confused